# Demonstration that two distances aren't equivalent.

Tags: real-analysis

I'd like to find an example that shows that the following distances aren't equivalent in $X=C([0,1])$:

$$d_\infty(f,g)=\sup_{x\in [0,1]}|f(x)-g(x)|$$
$$d_1(f,g)=\int_0^1|f(x)-g(x)|dx$$

Someone can help me?

Comment: What about $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=0$?

Comment: Try setting $f_n(0)=1$ and $f_n(x)=0$ on $[1/n,1]$. I let you guess what you should do on $(0,1/n)$.

Comment: But it is enough showing that they're different? I mean, with these two examples. I thought I should find a particular case in which I can't find the 2 costants of the definition of equivalent distances.

Comment: The best way to motivate these type of examples is think of things that'll be small in one norm but not in the other... E.g. clearly a function that's 1 on a small interval and 0 elsewhere will have norm 1 in the first but small norm in the second. Then you get something where taking a limit (corresponding to the interval "going to zero length") gives you a contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider two functions that are equal at "most" locations, but are different on a very small set. Then the $d_1$ distance will be small, where the $d_\infty$ distance will be relatively larger - this distance second doesn't care that the functions are close most of the time, it just looks for the biggest difference.

Concretely, you could try $f(x) \equiv 0$ and

$$
g_n(x) = \begin{cases} 1 - n x &: 0 \leq x \leq \frac{1}{n}, \\
0 &: \frac{1}{n} < x \leq 1.
\end{cases}
$$

Then $d_\infty(f,g_n) = 1$, while $d_1(f,g_n) = 1/2n$.

Now, let's assume these metrics are equivalent. Then, among other things$^*$, there needs to be a constant such that

$$
C d_\infty(f,g) \leq d_1(f,g)
$$

for all $f,g$. But, as we have seen

$$
d_\infty(f,g_n) = 1 \\
d_1(f,g_n) = \frac{1}{2n}
$$

and there is no positive constant so that
$$
C \leq \frac{1}{2n}
$$
for all $n$.

*: of course, the other thing that would have to hold is 
$$
\widetilde C d_1(f,g) \leq d_\infty(f,g)
$$
for some other constant $\widetilde C$ and all $f,g$. But, this is true:

$$
d_1(f,g) = \int_0^1 |f(x) - g(x)| \,dx \leq \int_0^1 \sup_{x \in [0,1]} |f(x) - g(x)|\,dx = \int_0^1 d_\infty(f,g) \,dx = d_\infty(f,g)
$$